# Mongoose Shema for Json Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a mongoose schema for a json object which i will recieve from an api.
The json object has an element payMoneyid which is like this

```
payuMoneyId: {
    "paymentId": 1112253696,
    "splitIdMap": [{
        "amount": 10.00,
        "splitPaymentId": 1112253697,
        "merchantId": 4825051,
        "splitId": "splitId1"
    }]
}
```

I have written a schema is this how it's supposed to be or it's wrong?

```
const formSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
payuMoneyId: {
        paymentId: {
          type: Number
        },
        splitIdMap: {
          type: Mixed
        }
      }
})
```

Comment: Is `payuMoneyId` an actual JSON string or is just a Javascript object?

Comment: payuMoneyId is an element in the returned Json file @codemonkey

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have just two top level fields - a number and an array of objects. Here is how to mirror that structure in a mongoose schema:

```
const formSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    paymentId: Number,
    splitIdMap: [
        new mongoose.Schema({
            amount: Number,
            splitPaymentId: Number,
            merchantId: Number,
            splitId: String
        })
    ]
})
```